# Simple php script add user to mysql database not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The script was working fine adding new users before I added the code to check if the user already exists in the database, which is the part that I can not figure out why it is not working. It is a test-only environment for Android apps, so I prefer the simplest possible version.

```
<?php

require_once 'connect_db.php';
$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $admin_name, $admin_pwd, $database);
if($conn->connect_error) {
    die($conn->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_REQUEST["username"]) && isset($_REQUEST["email"]) && isset($_REQUEST["password"]) && isset($_REQUEST["user_type"])) {
    echo "Welcome ". $_REQUEST['username']. "<br />";

    $name = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $pwd = $_REQUEST['password'];
    $user_type = $_REQUEST['user_type'];

    // first check if user already exists
    $query = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE `EMAIL` = '$email'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "Error inserting user into database. User already exists";
    } else {
        // then do insert new user
        $query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO users (`NAME`, `EMAIL`, `PWD`, `USER_TYPE`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$pwd', '$user_type')";

        if ($conn->query($query_insert_user) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $query_insert_user . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }

    $result->close();
    $conn->close();

} else {
    echo "Error inserting user into database. Missing user parameters";
}
```

?>

Comment: You're wide open for SQL injection. You're using mysqli, so take advantage of prepared statements and bind_param. Check for mysqli errors instead of checking that the query is true.

Comment: try removing this line: if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);

Answer (score -1):

change the line

$query = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE `EMAIL` = '$email'";

to

$query = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE `EMAIL` = '".$email."' ";

Answer (score -1):

I was not able to test it, but at first glance I would suggest:

- change your query to Jesper's suggestion (although " " should expand your variable, but...)
- and could it be the use of `mysqli_num_rows($result)` when `$result->num_rows` should be used for OOP? Have a look at [PHP manual mysqli-result.num-rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Some sample code from a friend just works. I changed to:

```
// first check if user already exists
    $query = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE NAME = '$name' OR EMAIL = '$email'";
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,$query));
    if (isset($result)){
        echo 'username or email already exist';
```